# Implement WebDAV connection in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, webdav

I've been searching around this forum and Google, but I can't find anything that helps me. I need to be able to connect to a WebDAV server, type in a username and password to get access and show the folders and files in my iPhone app. Just like the free iPhone app called WebDAV Nav.

Seems like the question is asked a lot, but no one really has an answer for it?

Does anyone know if there's a sample project out there, that could get me on the right track?

I've tried WTClient and flyingcode webdav.

Comment: And what was the problem with WTClient and Flyingcode?

Comment: Hi..have you found solution for this question? Because I am facing the same problem as yours. I have used sftp too for secure file transfer but connection error was there.....If you are successful, then kindly give me some reference ...Thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 1):

Both flycode's [`WebDAV`](https://github.com/ccgus/flycode/tree/master/WebDAV) and [`WTClient`](http://code.google.com/p/wtclient/) are a few years old, seem incomplete and have a few errors.

When I try WTClient with a WebDAV server I get the response

`This URL can be accessed only with a WebDAV compatible software program.`

When I try the flycode WebDAV code, `it fails to parse the server directory listing response correctly`. I managed to modify the code in `FMWebDAVRequest` to look for slightly different XML elementNames in the response

> eg "response" instead of "D:response", "href" instead of "D:href",
>   "resourcetype" instead of ":getcontenttype"

Then it worked, successfully retrieving the directory listing.

But should I continue to tweak this code, try something more robust or roll my own? What have others done/used?